# Keep the session when page is refresh in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing the authentication and authorization for my single page web app using the process [here](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec).

But when I refresh my page, I still get the login page though session is active at server side.

Any solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are likely required. Enable them with withCredentials

```
angular.module('myApp')

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}])
```